# fill combobox using bindingsource

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, bindingsource

on windows form all textbox and combobox is bind from acctPackageBindingSource . My problem with biniding in combobox that display only int value means that is coming form acctPackage  . And i want to display the name means 'Displaymember' of that value . That one is coming form different table name is sysCode. So how can i display the display member perfectly .  Below is my code

```
 // Here the all value is coming form Syscode table .

  public void FillDropDown()
    {
        if (_commonComponent == null)
            _commonComponent = new CommonComponent();

        List<SysCode> _syscode = _commonComponent.GetByTableCodeForIncomeDedMapping("19");
        bindingSourceSysCode.DataSource = _syscode;

        packageCodeComboBox.DataSource = bindingSourceSysCode;
        packageCodeComboBox.DisplayMember = "Desclong2";
        packageCodeComboBox.ValueMember = "PackageCode";

    }



//This part is bind my all value on the form 

  private void FillAcctPackage()
    {
        if (_commonComponent == null)
            _commonComponent = new CommonComponent();

        acctPackageBindingSource.DataSource = _commonComponent.GetAcctPackge();



    }
```